# Set default value for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to set a default value for a dropdown that I've got. The dropdown features all 12 months. It is dynamically filled. However, I'm trying to make it so that the default dropdown value is the current month. I'm using KnockoutJS

The following code is how I'm sending information to the dropdown html code.

```
            self.setMonthData = (data: any) => {
            var len = data.List.length,
                i;

            var monthData = [];

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                self.monthData.push(
                    {
                        name: data.List[i].month,
                        month: data.List[i].monthNumber
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
                <select id="monthSelect" class="select select2" style="margin: 10px;"
                    data-bind="options: monthData,
                                optionsText: 'name',
                                optionsValue: 'month'">
                <option></option>
            </select>
```

This code is how the page loads which features the dropdown.

```
        $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        getGridData(initialMonth, initialYear);
        viewModel.load();

        $("#monthSelect").on('change', function () {
            var month = $('#monthSelect').find("option:selected").val();
            var year = $('#yearSelect').find("option:selected").val();
            viewModel.loadChangesData(month, year);
            getGridData(month, year);
        });

        $("#yearSelect").on('change', function () {
            var month = $('#monthSelect').find("option:selected").val();
            var year = $('#yearSelect').find("option:selected").val();
            viewModel.loadChangesData(month, year);
            getGridData(month, year);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code isnt working is because you need to set the value of the select. By setting the value binding in a select control you are telling your ViewModel which observable you want to hold the currently selected option in your select dropdown.

As an aside, if you are using an array you probably dont need a month number as it is implicit in the position of each month in the monthData array. i.e. Jan is stored at index 0, Feb at index 1, etc.

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.months = [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
  ];
  self.selectedMonth = ko.observable(self.months[new Date().getMonth()]);
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Defaulted to current month:
<select data-bind="options: months, value: selectedMonth"></select>
<br/>
<br/>
Selected Month: <b data-bind="text: selectedMonth"></b>
```